# JTS Topology Suite in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jts

I am currently developing and android application and require to do some spatial queries for which I ended up in deciding to use JTS topological suite. However, I could not find proper documentation of how to add the JTS Topological Suite in my Android Studio Project. Could anyone please let me know if there is a proper documentation for this or if you could tell me how to add JTS in android studio, then it would be of great help. Sorry, if its a very basic question as I am a new by in android development.

Comment: Does the Maven section of the JTS usage guide (https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/USING.md#using-jts-with-maven) help at all?

(Sadly, I have almost no experience with Android development.  I'm part of the JTS team, and I'd like to make sure you we document JTS use on Android.)

Comment: @GeoMesaJim Thanks a lot. :) it certainly helped.. Could you please also let me know if JTS has an integration for Web Feature Service ?

Comment: GeoServer is an open source server which implements the Web Feature Service using JTS and GeoTools.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same problem , I found a solution , hope this helps .

1. Add the following lines to your app module's build.gradle file to
   include the JTS library in your project:

   ```
   dependencies {
          implementation 'org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.18.0'
   }
   ```
2. Sync your project with Gradle.
3. You can now use the JTS library in your Android project. In your
   Java code, you can import the JTS classes as follows:

   ```
   import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Circle;
   import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
   import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
   import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
   import com.vividsolutions.jts.algorithm.CentroidArea;
   ```